# View related categories in order of posts

Tags: wp-query, loop

In the category page I have a query that displays the last post of each category related to a parent category. The problem is that this list has just displayed the categories in alphabetical order, but I want it to be displayed by date posts.

**Order by posts (I want that!):**

Category B

Post: 10/03/16

Category A

Post: 10/01/16

Category C

Post: 09/30/16

**Order by categories:**

Category A

Post: 10/01/16

Category B

Post: 10/03/16

Category C

Post: 09/30/16

```
<?php
$thiscat =  get_query_var('cat');
$catobject = get_category($thiscat,false);
$parentcat = $catobject->category_parent;
$news_cats = get_categories( "parent=$parentcat" );

if( $parentcat ) {

$news_query  = new WP_Query();

foreach ( $news_cats as $news_cat ) :

$news_query->query( array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', 
    'cat'  => array($news_cat->term_id),
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'category__not_in' => $thiscat,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    )
);

while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : $news_query->the_post(); 

get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

endforeach; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the posts by category and only inside your loop you get the published date. By that time you cannot change the order anymore, unless you postpone echoing the posts to a second loop, where you order them by date. So, inside your foreach loop you do this:

```
$post_array[$news_query->ID] = $news_query->post_date;
```

This gives you an array of ID and data pairs. Now you can sort this array by date like this:

```
arsort ($post_array); // use asort to order the other way around
```

Now you can loop through the array like this

```
foreach ($post_array as $post_ID => $post_date) {
  get_post ($post_ID);
  get_template_part ('content',get_post_format());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried here but failed. In what order should I add these codes?

Comment: You add them in the order as given. The first inside you foreach loop, where you won't need the while loop for displaying. The after the foreach loop the sorting and second foreach loop.